# Change context properties from QML code

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Main goal: have a context property that is set by a item defined into a QML file (say `file_1.qml`), and which will be accessed at runtime by other item defined in a different QML file (say `file_2.qml`).

Question: Is it possible to set a new context property in `file_1.qml` and then read this property in `file_2.qml`?

(edit)

For example, I would need to use a value from file_2.qml in file_1.qml:

file_1.qml:

```
(...)
UiController.but_generate__onClicked(
   getContextProperty("sbx_money_quantity_value"),
   cal_daysoff.visibleMonth)
(...)
```

file_2.qml:

```
(...)
SpinBox {
        id: sbx_money_quantity
        objectName: "sbx_money_quantity"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        minimumValue: 0
        maximumValue: 100000
        value: 20000


        onChanged: setContextProperty("sbx_money_quantity_value",value)
    }
(...)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show sample code which describes the problem?

Comment: I added an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an item in some file from another one due to scope limitation. So you just need some proxy root object or may be some global singleton object or just to pass reference to one object to another one. For example:

**File1.qml**

```
Item {   
    property someValue: 1
}
```

**File2.qml**

```
Item {
    property variant ref: null
    onChanged: ref.someValue = 2;
}
```

**main.qml**

```
File1 {
    item: file1
}
File2 {
    item: file2
    ref: file1
}
```